# How to remove the first character in a line which contains a specific string from Linux command line?

Tags: bash

I need to frequently comment/uncomment a line containing a string with "#". For example:

```
Don't touch this line.
Touch this LINE instead.
```

<==>

```
Don't touch this line.
#Touch this LINE instead.
```

I was able to comment with sed, but had problem to uncomment. I tried command

```
sed 's/^#\(.*\)LINE/\1/' hosts
```

It did put a "#" at the beginning, but also removed LINE and the following characters, which made it:

```
Don't touch this line.
#Touch this
```

What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to make `s` work only on lines that match a certain pattern, the substitution can be quite simple then.

This will remove leading `#` from lines that contain `LINE`:

```
sed '/LINE/ s/^#//'
```

This will remove all leading `#` characters:

```
sed '/LINE/ s/^#*//'
```

This will add one `#` character:

```
sed '/LINE/ s/^/#/'
```

Obviously you cannot remove `#` that isn't there, but you can add `#` while a leading `#` is already there. An improvement to the above command that doesn't modify already commented lines:

```
sed '/^\([^#].*\|\)LINE/ s/^/#/'
```

It detects `^LINE` or `^[^#].*LINE` where `^` matches the beginning of the line and `[^#]` matches a non-`#`. It's possible to improve the command further, so `#` with leading blanks at the beginning of a line will not be commented out again; I won't do this here.

Anyway, use `/regex/ s…`. If your regex happens to contain slashes, escape them with `\`; or choose another character to embrace the regex, but then you need to escape the opening one (e.g. `\@regex@ s…`).